# Getting errors while building the C++ REST sdk on eclipse, ubuntu

Tags: c++, rest, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-cdt, casablanca

I tried to use cpp REST sdk using ubuntu on eclipse. I added the required header files to `usr/local/includes`. When I try to build the following code I get some errors.

```
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::experimental::listener;

int main() {

    http_listener listner(L"http://localhost/restdemo");

    return 0;
}
```

These are some of the errors.

```
  trying to instantiate ‘template<class _Function> pplx::cancellation_token_registration pplx::cancellation_token::register_callback(const _Function&) const’   CheckRest       line 6306, external location: /usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h   C/C++ Problem

  trying to instantiate ‘template<class _Function> pplx::cancellation_token_registration pplx::cancellation_token::register_callback(const _Function&) const’   CheckRest       line 996, external location: /usr/local/include/pplx/pplxcancellation_token.h   C/C++ Problem

  trying to instantiate ‘template<class T> void pplx::details::_CancellationTokenState::TokenRegistrationContainer::for_each(T)’    CheckRest       line 451, external location: /usr/local/include/pplx/pplxcancellation_token.h   C/C++ Problem
```